# Swift array slicing with a range in the subscript

Tags: swift

What's going on here?

```
var foo: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4]
var bar: [UInt8] = foo[1...2] // 'Range<Pos>' is not convertible to 'Int'
```

But this compiles fine:

```
var foo: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4]
var bar = foo[1...2]
```

The docs only explicitly mention this in terms of replacement:

```
shoppingList[4...6] = ["Bananas", "Apples"]
```

So what exactly does `Array[Range]` return then? And what's the simplest way to fetch objects between two array indices?

Comment: Swift really needs better error messages...

Comment: @jtbandes It _really_ does...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`struct Array` declares `subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> Slice<T>`. Therefore, `bar`'s type should be `Slice<UInt8>`, not `[UInt8]`. `Slice` conforms to the same protocols as `Array`, so the rest of your code won't need to change, and you can choose to just leave off the type annotation. (Or, you could use `Array(foo[1...2])` to convert it to an array if you really want to.)

Comment: It's worth noting that the documentation for ArraySlice (which is returned in Swift 2 rather than Slice) notes that you shouldn't use an ArraySlice as long term storage check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ArraySlice_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:VSs10ArraySlice). Also ArraySlice doesn't seem to index from 0 so you need to use .startIndex (which looks like a bug in Swift 2 as the documentation says .startIndex this should be always zero)